# Vagrant unable to mount shared folders - No such file or directory

Tags: vagrant, shared-directory, vagrant-windows, synced-folder

I have this *Vagrantfile*

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
  config.vm.hostname = "app.local"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.20.20"

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ['dmode=774','fmode=775']

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = "MyBox"
    vb.memory = 512
    vb.cpus = 2
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "install.sh"
end
```

that I used so far without problems (on *Ubuntu* and *Windows*). On Windows 10, I have upgraded both *Oracle VM Virtual Box* (5.1.16) and *Vagrant* (1.9.2) and now I get this error when trying to install the box:

> Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
>   because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
>   made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
>   Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
>   guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty 
>   Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:
>
> ```
>  mount -t vboxsf -o dmode=774,fmode=775,uid=1000,gid=1000 vagrant /vagrant
>
>  The error output from the command was:
>  : No such file or directory
> ```

I also see this:

> GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.1.16) and guest (4.3.36) do not match.
>      * Stopping VirtualBox Additions

and then it looks like the GuestAdditions is removed and the 5.1.16 version is installed, steps that ends with:

> vboxadd.sh: Building Guest Additions kernel modules.   vboxadd.sh:
>   Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions.
>        Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.

After this, I still get:

> Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
>   Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.3.36   VBoxService inside the vm
>   claims: 5.1.16   Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...   Got
>   different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:   Virtualbox
>   on your host claims:   4.3.36   VBoxService inside the vm claims:
>   5.1.16   Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Virtualbox 5.1.16 (maybe only Windows 10?).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796016/vagrant-unable-to-mount-shared-folders

Comment: @Fender, true. Had to go back to using 5.1.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was fixed in 5.1.18. Updating to the latest version fixed the problem for me.

[Change Log (Version 5.1.18)](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-5.1#v18):

> - Shared Folders: fixed case insensitive filename access (5.1.16 regression; Windows guests only; bug #16549)
> - Shared Folders: fixed access to long pathes (5.1.16 regression; Windows guests only; bugs #14651, #16564)

Comment: Indeed, the long paths problem has been fixed, finally