# Vagrant unable to mount shared folders

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have a fresh installation of scotchbox. I have been trying to install this, on a mac it normally works without problems, now im using windows and im starting to get all sorts of problems with it.

Solved most of them, however I cannot solve this one for some reason.

```
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /var/www => C:/Users/kevin/Desktop/programeren/scotch-box-master
Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o dmode=777,fmode=666,uid=1000,gid=1000 var_www /var/www

The error output from the command was:

: No such file or directory

C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\programeren\scotch-box-master>
```

My vagrantfile:

```
    # -*- mode: ruby -*-
    # vi: set ft=ruby :

    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

        config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
        config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
        config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
        config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

    # Optional NFS. Make sure to remove other synced_folder line too
    #config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"] }

end
```

I have tried installing a vagrant plugin called vagrant-vbguest, this didn't work. Any ideas how to solve this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Greetings,

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using VirtualBox 5.1.16, there have been similar issues reported. It looks like downgrading to 5.1.14 has solved this for most of them. You could give it a try.

Comment: Sir, you are amazing! Thanks